# Stochastic Matrices Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, markov-chains

Let matrix $A$ be some $n \times n$ stochastic matrix: the sum of the entries in each column sum up to $1$. It is easy to see that if $\mathbf{x}$ is some stochastic vector then $\mathbf{q} = A \mathbf{x}$ is itself a stochastic vector.

My question is as follows, suppose we are given $\mathbf{q}$ and $A$. Are there sufficient conditions on $A$ that guarantee $\mathbf{x}$ is a stochastic vector (where naturally $\mathbf{x} = A^{-1}\mathbf{q}$ when $A$ is invertible)?

Obviously if $A$ is the identity matrix, then my statement holds, but what more can be said?

Edit: As noted below by Igor Rivin, this holds if $\mathbf{q}$ is a multiple of the Perron-Frobenius eigenvector of $A$. I then ask, what if it is not a multiple of the dominant eigenvector? (Since it is easy to see that this condition is not *necessary*).

Comment: What is an example that shows that the condition is not necessary?

Comment: Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/3 & 1/5 \\
    0 & 2/3 & 2/5 \\
    0 & 0 & 2/5 
    \end{pmatrix}$$
and $$\mathbf{q} = \begin{pmatrix} .3\\ .5\\.2
    \end{pmatrix}$$
The eigenvalues are $\lambda = 1, 2/3, 2/5$, corresponding to eigenvectors $$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\0
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 1\\0
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1/2\\ -3/2\\1
    \end{pmatrix}$$
Of which the first is dominant. Clearly $\mathbf{q}$ is not a multiple of the dominant eigenvector.

Comment: However, $\mathbf{x} = A^{-1}\mathbf{q}$ is $$\begin{pmatrix} 1/20\\ 9/20\\1/2
    \end{pmatrix}$$
which is clearly a stochastic vector.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful, but when $A$ is invertible, by Farkas' lemma, it suffices to guarantee that $y^TA$ has a negative entry (i.e. it is not a nonnegative vector) whenever $y^Tq<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your $q$ must be a multiple of the Perron-Frobenius eigenvector of $A.$

Comment: Dear Igor, that still seems to be an awfully weak sufficient condition. I have amended the question in order to ask for more.